# How to edit manually pdb structures?

Tags: pdb

I would like to manually movement some b-sheets from a 3D structure of my PDF protein to represent a change in its structure.There some tool i can do that?

Comment: Using PyMOL, (see Nicolai's answer and my comment), you can also generate movie of a transition between two structures (conformations). Question: why do you want to edit the structure manually?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly [pymol](https://pymol.org/2/) can edit pdb structures (as well as visualize them).

I've used a student version though (which is a free full version) and I'm not quite sure if its possible to use pymol without buying a license nowadays (though the source code is still open source, so can in principle always install it from that)

Comment: PyMOL 0.99rc6 is available for free: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pymol/files/Legacy (i have been using this version since 2006 and it still fulfills all my macromolecular visualization needs)